# jQuery tabbed content slider with 2 content bodies

Tags: jquery, html

I'm in the process of trying to build a tabbed content slider that controls 2 different div's.
Heres an image of what I had in mind http://img263.imageshack.us/img263/2295/protol.jpg the title tab controls the content box and the thumbnail box so basically the thumbnails and content is unique to the title tab and when you select a thumbnail it updates the content box.

Essentially there are 2 ways to update the content box selecting a title or thumbnail, I'm going to use php to generate the html required with unique id's but beyond that I'm stumped when it comes to the jQuery.

I've tried but I can't seem to get my head around jQuery, I've been able to make a simple content slider but the model I'm trying to achieve is too advanced for my current knowledge.

So I'm just wondering if someone can point me in the right direction and to what functions I should be looking at, etc.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will give you an idea of how to achieve what you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/SQHgu/9/

Note that you can also load a part of a page.

`$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');`

You may also want to load 'full' content when you click on title, so that the thumbs click function is simply a fadeIn() fadeOut() effect.

Hope it helps.